# Need help when dealing with Excel Complex Data in MSTest

Tags: c#, excel, automation, odbc, mstest

Currently, I am fetching data from particular sheet where it matched a "Key" value - But now I want to access data from all sheets where it matches "Key" value

In my excel - I have two sheets: LogInUserData and Sheet2

Now in LogInUserData
        Key Email   Password    RememberMe
LogInSuccessfully   a@a.a   a   0

And in Sheet2
        Key Klarna
LogInSuccessfully   Demo

Now, I want to access values of Key "Loginsuccessfully" from both the sheets - I have code but that fetches it from only first sheet and not from other - so how do i access complex data sheet from excel

I'm using ODBC Connection

```
    public static string TestDataFileConnection(string fileName)
    {

        string Filename = "C:\\Users\\PalakS\\source\\repos\\Daily update\\UnitTestProject2 - 10-04\\UnitTestProject2\\ExcelData\\LogInPageData.xlsx";
        string connectionString = string.Format("Dsn=Excel Files;READONLY=false;DBQ={0};", Filename);
        System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand odbcCmd = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand("", new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(connectionString));
        return connectionString;
    }

    public static T GetTestData<T>(string fileName, string sheet, string keyName)
    {
        using (var connection = new
                      OdbcConnection(TestDataFileConnection(fileName)))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var query = string.Format("select * from [{0}$]where key = '{1}'", sheet, keyName);
            var value = connection.Query<T>(query).FirstOrDefault();
            connection.Close();
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Function Call:

```
    LogInUserModel user = AccessExcelData.GetTestData<LogInUserModel>("LogInPageData.xlsx", "LogInUserData", "LogInSuccessfully");
        string email = user.Email.ToString();
```

Can anyone help in this - How do I manage Complex data in MSTest with Excel

Comment: Will there ever be more than one result (user)?

Comment: Not for now - Key value is like a primary key for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the solution you are looking for but the one with the least amount of change required to your code...

Since there will only be one result across all sheets (primary key) then check if the first query is null and then run again on sheet2 if it is.

Example:

```
LogInUserModel user = AccessExcelData.GetTestData<LogInUserModel>("LogInPageData.xlsx", "LogInUserData", "LogInSuccessfully");

if (user is null)
{
    user = AccessExcelData.GetTestData<LogInUserModel>("LogInPageData.xlsx", "Sheet2", "LogInSuccessfully");
}
string email = user.Email.ToString();
```

Comment: Yeah this solution might not help :(